# How to put a view in another view in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here I have a MainController in which I have two actions named Create and PhotoUpload. Here is the code for Create action.

```
// GET: Main/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Main/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Email,Password,FirstName,LastName,Gender,Birthday,ProfileImage,AboutUser")] User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(user);
        }
```

Here is the code for PhotoUpload action.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult PhotoUpload(PhotoModel model)
        {
            if (model.PhotoFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(model.PhotoFile.FileName);
                var filePath = Server.MapPath("/Content/Users/Images");
                string savedFileName = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
                model.PhotoFile.SaveAs(savedFileName);

            }
            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult PhotoUpload()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

And these are the User and Photo models. This is the User Model

```
public partial class User
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public User()
        {
            this.Friends = new HashSet<Friend>();
            this.Friends1 = new HashSet<Friend>();
            this.Photos = new HashSet<Photo>();
        }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        public string ProfileImage { get; set; }
        public string AboutUser { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Friend> Friends1 { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the PhotoModel

```
public class PhotoModel
    {
        [Required]
        public HttpPostedFileBase PhotoFile { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is what I am getting as a view now. This is my /Main/Create View
[image]

And this is my /Main/PhotoUpload View

[image]

Now I want to put this PhotoUpload view instead of `ProfileImage` thing inside my Create View. Where do I change this and how?

Comment: Can you use the built in conventions? `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.PhotoFile)`

Comment: Well I am only storing string(address) of photo in my database and I am adding the photo (.jpg or whatever) to a folder whenever I am doing database operations. So I can't use that convention since I am only storing a string in my database.

Comment: Maybe using `@Html.Action`

Comment: Use a view model that includes your `HttpPostedFileBase` property and save all data including the file in one method (there is no point having 2 separate forms - you can only submit one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `ViewModel` as that's the recommended practice for transferring data to and from views, in this case you can do the following as @StephenMuecke commented

**ViewModel**

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public string ProfileImage { get; set; }
    public string AboutUser { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase PhotoFile { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(UserViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        AddUser(model);
        SavePhoto(model.PhotoFile);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(user);
}
private void SavePhoto(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var filePath = Server.MapPath("/Content/Users/Images");
        string savedFileName = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
        file.SaveAs(savedFileName);
    }
}
private void AddUser(UserViewModel model)
{
    var user = new User
    {
        Email = model.Email, Password = model.Password, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, Gender = model.Gender, Birthday = model.Birthday, ProfileImage = model.ProfileImage, AboutUser = model.AboutUser
    };
    db.Users.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

*For further reading:*

- http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/188/view-model-design-and-use-in-razor-views
- http://rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp-net-mvc-applications/